# Generate random colors

Tags: php

I am using this code to generate random colors (which is working fine):

```
  {
       $r = rand(128,255); 
       $g = rand(128,255); 
       $b = rand(128,255); 
       $color = dechex($r) . dechex($g) . dechex($b);
       return "#".$color;
  }
```

I am just wondering if is there a way/combination to generate only the Bright colors?

Thank you

Comment: You can generate colors in HSL/HSV and then convert to RGB. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original code doesn't work as you'd expect - if a low number is generated you might get `#1ffff` (1 being the low red value) - which is invalid. It is much more stable to use this:

```
echo "rgb(".$r.",".$g.",".$b.")";
```

Since `rgb(123,45,67)` is perfectly valid colour specification.

Along similar lines, you can generate random numbers for hsl:

```
echo "hsl(".rand(0,359).",100%,50%)";
```

This will generate fully saturated, normal lightness colours of any hue. However, note that only recent browers support HSL so you may be better off coerting to RGB if browser support is a concern.

Answer (score 3):

```
function getRandomColor() {
    $rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
    $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];
    return $color;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to detect wether a background-color is light or dark, and then to choose the right font-color, so font-color is still readable/visible on a randomly generated or user-inputted background-color:

```
//$hex: #AB12CD
function ColorLuminanceHex($hex=0) {
  $hex = str_replace('#', '', $hex);
  $luminance = 0.3 * hexdec(substr($hex,0,2)) + 0.59 * hexdec(substr($hex,2,2)) + 0.11 * hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
  return $luminance;
}


$background_color = '#AB12CD';
$luminance = ColorLuminanceHex($background_color);
if($luminance < 128) {
  $color = '#FFFFFF';
}
else {
  $color = '#000000';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using chakroun yesser's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16101648/5435780) above, i created this function:

```
function generateRandomColor($count=1){
    if($count > 1){
        $color = array();
        for($i=0; $count > $i; $i++)
            $color[count($color)] = generateRandomColor();
    }else{
        $rand = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'f'));
        $color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];
    }
    return $color;
}
```